# Sum of conservative field is conservative?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Does a sum of conservative fields is conservative?

I mean, can I divide the field to sub-fields and show that each one is conservative and thus conclude that the field is conservative.

Comment: What does "union" mean here -- just the (pointwise) sum of the fields?

Comment: I mean lets say that g and h are conservative on a given region. can I say that F=g+h is conservative?

Comment: Of course, with any one of the definitions of conservative field. Pick your favorite definition and justify it! But you really should replace "union" with "sum" in the title and make it explicit in your question.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes. Consider a decomposition of vector field $v$
$$v=\sum_i v_i$$
If each sub-vector field $v_i$ is conservative, that is there exists $\phi_i$ such that
$$v_i=-\nabla\phi_i$$
Then we have
$$v=-\sum_i\nabla\phi_i=-\nabla(\sum_i\phi_i)$$
which shows $v$ is also conservative.